# Finding min and max using partial differentiation. Find the angle and the dimensions that will make the carrying capacity as large as possible.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations

Here is an image of the problem...

[image]

So labeled the bottom base as $x$ and the upper base as $y$ this helped me come up with two equations, one for perimeter $P$ and one for area $A$:

$$P = 24 = x  + 2\frac{(y-x)}{2cos\theta}$$

and

$$A = \frac{x+y}{2} \times \frac{y-x}{2}tan\theta$$

I did some simplifying but I am stuck on which variable I should isolate and from which equation, or if maybe I've made a mistake? Answer in the book is $\theta = \pi/3 $ and the legs of the trapezoid $= 8$ cm

Comment: Posing problems has much of an art. Change the variables to the ones the solution suggests.

Comment: Im assuming x or y would be the best way to go, taking it out of the perimeter equation, but I would also like some confirmation on whether the equations I came up with are even correct

Comment: They are correct.

Comment: Isolating $\theta$ would be a mess, and not to mention that one is $sec\theta$ and the other is $sin\theta / cos\theta$. And when I try to isolate x or y it becomes a mess, leading me to believe something is wrong

Comment: The fact that you find a particular formulation hard to work with doesn't mean it's _wrong,_ but it may indicate that you would benefit by thinking of a different formulation from first principles.

Comment: On the other hand even this may not be as bad as it looks. You might be able to use the fact that $\sec^2 \theta = 1+\tan^2\theta.$

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what you guys are seeing, a detailed explanation would help me see what I should be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $y$ the amount bended up on both sides and by $x$ the remaining base. Then $x+2y=24$ and 
$$A=(x+y\cos\theta) y\sin\theta=\bigl(24-y(2-\cos\theta)\bigr)y\sin\theta=: f(y,\theta)\ .$$
One computes
$$\eqalign{f_y&=2\sin\theta(12-2y+y\cos\theta)\ ,\cr
f_\theta&=y\bigl(2\cos^2\theta+2\cos\theta(12-y)-1\bigr)\ .\cr}$$
Put $\cos\theta=:u$. From $f_y=0$ we get $y={12\over2-u}$, and $f_\theta=0$ then leads to $u={1\over2}$. We therefore have a stationary point at $y=8$, $\theta={\pi\over3}$.

This means that the optimal gutter is half of a regular hexagon.

Comment: Could you help me with.this ques. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263164/consider-a-right-angled-triangle-pqr-right-angled-at-p-i-e-angle-qpr-90

Answer (score 1):

The gutter is formed from the large strip of metal by bending a smaller strip upward on either side of the larger strip. Let the width of the smaller strip be $r.$

The trapezoidal cross-section of the gutter can be divided into a rectangle of width $$x = 24 - 2r \tag1$$ 
between two right triangles with hypotenuse $r$
and legs $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta.$
Then the upper base of the trapezoid is $$y = x + 2r\cos\theta.\tag2$$
From $(2)$ we get $$2r = \frac{y-x}{\cos\theta},\tag3$$ 
and then from $(1)$ we get
$$24 = x + 2r = x  + \frac{y-x}{\cos\theta}.\tag4$$
This is the same as your "perimeter" equation. (You were wrong to set $P=24$ if $P$ was meant to be the perimeter; the perimeter is actually $24+y.$
But this is irrelevant to the problem, since you have no reason to make any further use of the symbol $P.$)

The height of the trapezoid is $h = r\sin\theta.$
Using $(3)$ to substitute for $r,$ we have
$$h = \frac{y-x}{2\cos\theta}\sin\theta = \frac{y-x}{2}\tan\theta.$$
The area of the trapezoid is therefore
$$A = \frac{x+y}{2}h = \frac{x+y}{2} \left(\frac{y-x}{2}\tan\theta\right).$$
Again that agrees with what you found.

You can use $(4)$ to eliminate one variable from the equation for area:
$\frac{24-x}{y-x} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta},$
so $$\left(\frac{24-x}{y-x}\right)^2 = \sec^2\theta = 1 + \tan^2\theta.$$
Therefore
$$A = \frac{x+y}{2} \left(\frac{y-x}{2}\right)
\sqrt{\left(\frac{24-x}{y-x}\right)^2 - 1}.$$
You can further simplify this by maximizing $A^2$ instead of $A$
(to eliminate the square root) 
and perhaps substituting a new variable for $y - x.$

Or you could start over. From $(2),$
$y = 24 - 2r + 2r\cos\theta.$
From basic trigonometry, $h = r\sin\theta = r\sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta}.$
The area of the trapezoid is therefore
$$A = \tfrac12(x+y)h = (12 - r + r\cos\theta)r\sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta}.\tag5$$
You can then substitute a new variable name for $\cos\theta$ and optimize.
Alternatively, since 
$r\cos\theta = \sqrt{r^2 - r^2\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{r^2 - h^2},$
$$A = \tfrac12(x+y)h = (12 - r + \sqrt{r^2 - h^2})h.\tag6$$
I think $(5)$ looks easier to work with than $(6),$ since
you can just square both sides to eliminate the square root,
but you can also take partial derivatives of the right-hand side of 
$(6)$ directly.